# contrain dimension of an image in a div

Tags: css

i have a div (which is a 200x200 square) inside which i'd like to place a 180x60 image at the top and then some text.

```
<div class='box_item'>
    <img src="<? echo base_url(); ?>img2/avengers_assemble_small.jpg" class='box_item_img'/>
    <h4>some text...</h4>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.box_item {
    float: left;
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 0;
}
.box_item_img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

i would expect the image to appear at the top of the box with the dimensions specified by the box_item_img class.
instead, i get a stretched image that expands to almost the entire box (a 5px margin is left at the top and on the left).

ideas?

Comment: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4MfPY/) - seems to do exactly what you wrote in the CSS.

Comment: To me your code is producing the expected output as well.

Comment: Check your image's actual dimensions; is it cropped to 180x60? Otherwise, seems fine to me: http://dabblet.com/gist/2466164

Comment: @JoeJ It doesn't have to be cropped if you explicitly specify its dimensions, as Patrick did.

Comment: @Shedal I understand that, but it may correct his stretched image problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9yf6H/

Comment: Hi All - you're all correct - i was about to post that i've found another bit of the css that was related to the containing div (#main_content img {width:200px; height:200px etc.. }. What i'm not clear now is why that superceded the #box_item_img selector. shouldn't this win being more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rules you gave are working fine. There must be some other styling rules interfering, for example, a generic `img` rule.

Just inspect the `img` and `div` elements in FireBug or Chrome developer tools and look what rules are applied to each of them. Then try removing the most suspicious rules one by one to find the real cause.